React (using UmiJS)/Flask Image Upload and Delete Logic Not Working as Expected
I'm working on a web application using React with Ant Design for the frontend and Flask for the backend. I'm facing an issue with the logic related to uploading and deleting images for room entities. Here's a brief overview of the process:
Uploading Image: Users can upload images which are saved in a directory (The path is specified at the backend) and their paths are stored in a MySQL database table rooms and in a column image.
Editing Room: Users can edit room details, including changing or deleting the previously uploaded image.
Deleting Image: When an image is deleted during the edit process, it should remove the file from the server directory and update the database to remove the image path.
However, the image deletion is not working as expected. The image file remains in the directory and the path in the database is not updated after the edit.

Here is uploadFacilityImage.tsx:

import { UploadOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { FormattedMessage } from '@umijs/max';
import { Button, Upload, UploadFile, UploadProps } from 'antd';
import { RcFile } from 'antd/es/upload/interface';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

type FileType = File;
interface UploadRoomImageProps {
  initialFilePath?: string;
  onFileChange: (file: File | null, oldFilePath?: string) => void;
  onRemoveFile?: () => void;
  onMarkForDeletion?: (markedForDeletion: boolean) => void;
}

export const UploadRoomImage: React.FC<UploadRoomImageProps> = ({
  initialFilePath,
  onFileChange,
  onRemoveFile,
  onMarkForDeletion,
}) => {
  const [fileList, setFileList] = useState<UploadFile[]>([]);
  const [oldFilePath, setOldFilePath] = useState<string | null>(null);

  const baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000';
  useEffect(() => {
    if (initialFilePath) {
      setFileList([
        {
          uid: '-1',
          name: 'image.png',
          status: 'done',
          url: `${baseUrl}${initialFilePath}`,
        },
      ]);
      setOldFilePath(initialFilePath);
      console.log('Initial file set:', initialFilePath);
    }
  }, [initialFilePath]);

  const handleChange: UploadProps['onChange'] = ({ file, fileList: newFileList }) => {
    const updatedFileList = newFileList.slice(-1);
    setFileList(updatedFileList);

    if (updatedFileList.length > 0) {
      const file = updatedFileList[0].originFileObj as FileType;
      onFileChange(file, oldFilePath);
      setOldFilePath(null);
      console.log('File changed, oldFilePath cleared');
      onMarkForDeletion?.(false);
    } else {
      onFileChange(null);
    }
  };

  const handleRemove = () => {
    setFileList([]);
    onFileChange(null);
    if (onRemoveFile) {
      onRemoveFile();
    }
    if (oldFilePath) {
      onMarkForDeletion?.(true);
      console.log('Marked for deletion in UploadRoomImage:', true);
    }
    console.log('File removed, oldFilePath:', oldFilePath);
  };

  const onPreview = async (file: UploadFile) => {
    let src = file.url as string;
    if (!src) {
      src = await new Promise((resolve) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.readAsDataURL(file.originFileObj as RcFile);
        reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result as string);
      });
    }
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = src;
    const imgWindow = window.open(src);
    imgWindow?.document.write(image.outerHTML);
  };

  return (
    <div
      style={{
        display: 'flex',
        alignItems: 'center',
        gap: '8px',
        marginBottom: '16px',
      }}
    >
      <Upload
        listType="picture"
        fileList={fileList}
        onChange={handleChange}
        maxCount={1}
        beforeUpload={() => false}
        onRemove={handleRemove}
        onPreview={onPreview}
      >
        <Button icon={<UploadOutlined />}>
          <FormattedMessage id="label.upload" />
        </Button>
      </Upload>
    </div>
  );
};


Here's the relevant part of my React (roomIndex.tsx) component:

import { DeleteOutlined, EditOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import {
  ActionType,
  PageContainer,
  ProColumns,
  ProForm,
  ProFormText,
  ProTable,
} from '@ant-design/pro-components';
import { FormattedMessage, useIntl } from '@umijs/max';
import { Button, Input, message, Modal, theme as antdTheme } from 'antd';
import axios from 'axios';
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { hotelType } from '../../hotelType';
import { cities } from './cities';
import { indexRoomInterface, RoomInterface } from './interfaceRoom';
import { UploadRoomImage } from './uploadFacilityImage';

interface ConvertedRoomDetail {
  title: string;
  value: string;
}

const indexRoom = () => {
  const intl = useIntl();

  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { useToken } = antdTheme;
  const { token: theme } = useToken();
  const userID = localStorage.getItem('userID');
  const [oldFilePath, setOldFilePath] = useState<string | undefined>(undefined);
  const [file, setFile] = useState<File | null>(null);
  const [isImageRemoved, setIsImageRemoved] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const codeToHotelType = (code: number) => {
    const location = hotelType.find((loc) => loc.code === code);
    return location ? location.name : 'N/A';
  };

  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [editingRoom, setEditingRoom] = useState<indexRoomInterface | null>(null);

  const resetEditing = () => {
    setIsEditing(false);
    setEditingRoom(null);
    setFile(null);
    setOldFilePath(undefined);
    setIsImageRemoved(false);
  };
  const onEditRoom = (record: indexRoomInterface) => {
    setIsEditing(true);
    setEditingRoom({ ...record });
    setOldFilePath(record.images);
    setIsImageRemoved(false);
    console.log('Editing room:', record);
  };
  const onSubmitEditRoom = async () => {
    let imagePath = editingRoom?.images || '';
    console.log('isImageRemoved =', isImageRemoved);

    if (isImageRemoved && oldFilePath) {
      try {
        const response = await axios.delete('http://127.0.0.1:5000/delete-uploaded-room-image', {
          data: { image_path: oldFilePath },
        });
        if (response.status === 200) {
          imagePath = '';
          console.log('Image deleted:', oldFilePath);
        } else {
          throw new Error('Failed to delete image');
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error deleting image:', error);
        message.error('Failed to delete image.');
      }
    }

    if (file && !isImageRemoved) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('file', file);
      if (oldFilePath) {
        formData.append('old_file_path', oldFilePath);
        console.log('oldFilePath: ', oldFilePath);
      }

      try {
        const response = await axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload-room-image', formData);
        imagePath = response.data.filePath;
        console.log('New imagePath:', imagePath);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading image:', error);
        message.error('Failed to upload image.');
      }
    }

    try {
      const res = await axios.put(`http://127.0.0.1:5000/edit-room/${editingRoom?.id}`, {
        ...editingRoom,
        images: imagePath,
      });
      console.log('Room updated:', res.data);
      message.success('Room updated successfully.');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating room:', error);
      message.error('Failed to update room.');
    }
    resetEditing();
  };
...
return (
    <PageContainer
      header={{
        extra: [
          <Button
            type="primary"
            style={{ fontWeight: 'bold' }}
            onClick={() => {
              navigate('/addRoom');
            }}
          >
            <FormattedMessage id="property.create" />
          </Button>,
        ],
      }}
    >
      <ProTable<indexRoomInterface>
        onRow={(r) => ({
          onClick: () => {
            setSelectedRoom(r);
            setIsModalVisible(true);
          },
        })}
        headerTitle={
          <Input.Search
            placeholder={intl.formatMessage({ id: 'property.inputsearch' })}
            onSearch={(value) => {
              setSearchText(value);
            }}
          />
        }
        actionRef={actionRef}
        columns={columns}
        dataSource={filteredRooms}
        options={{
          reload: false,
          setting: false,
          density: false,
        }}
        rowKey="id"
        search={false}
        dateFormatter="string"
      />
<Modal
        title={intl.formatMessage({ id: 'property.edit' })}
        width="50%"
        open={isEditing}
        onCancel={() => {
          resetEditing();
        }}
        onOk={() => {
          console.log('OK button clicked, submitting edit');
          onSubmitEditRoom();
          resetEditing();
          // window.location.reload();
        }}
      >
        <ProForm
          submitter={{
            resetButtonProps: {
              style: {
                display: 'none',
              },
            },
            submitButtonProps: {
              style: {
                display: 'none',
              },
            },
          }}
        >
          <br />
          <ProFormText
            label={
              <span>
                <FormattedMessage id="property.add.name" />
                <span className="required-mark" style={{ backgroundColor: theme.colorPrimary }}>
                  <FormattedMessage id="require" />
                </span>
              </span>
            }
            value={editingRoom?.name}
            onChange={(e) => {
              setEditingRoom((pre) => {
                return { ...pre!, name: e.target.value };
              });
            }}
          />
...
<label>
            {' '}
            <FormattedMessage id="property.add.image" />
          </label>
          <br></br>
          <UploadRoomImage
            initialFilePath={editingRoom?.images ?? undefined}
            onFileChange={(file, oldFilePath) => {
              setFile(file);
              setOldFilePath(oldFilePath ?? undefined);
              setIsImageRemoved(false);
              console.log('File changed, isImageRemoved set to false');
            }}
            onRemoveFile={() => {
              setIsImageRemoved(true);
              setFile(null);
              setOldFilePath(editingRoom?.images ?? undefined);
              console.log('File removed, isImageRemoved set to true');
            }}
            onMarkForDeletion={(markedForDeletion) => {
              setIsImageRemoved(markedForDeletion);
              console.log('Marked for deletion in roomIndex:', markedForDeletion);
            }}
          />

Backend Flask route:
...
SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = True
ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS=set(['pdf','png','jpg','jpeg'])
UPLOAD_FACILITY_IMAGE_FOLDER = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), '..', 'myapp', 'public', 'imgs','room_image')
app.config['UPLOAD_FACILITY_IMAGE_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FACILITY_IMAGE_FOLDER
if not os.path.exists(UPLOAD_FACILITY_IMAGE_FOLDER):
    os.makedirs(UPLOAD_FACILITY_IMAGE_FOLDER)
...
# EDIT ROOM/HOTEL
@app.route("/edit-room/<id>", methods=["PUT"])
def roomUpdate(id):
    room = Room.query.filter_by(id=id).first()
    if room:
        room.name = request.json.get('name', room.name)
        room.name_en = request.json.get('name_en', room.name_en)
        room.notification_email = request.json.get('notification_email', room.notification_email)
        room.postcode = request.json.get('postcode', room.postcode)
        room.country = request.json.get('country', room.country)
        room.prefectures = request.json.get('prefectures', room.prefectures)
        room.city = request.json.get('city', room.city)
        room.building_room_number = request.json.get('building_room_number', room.building_room_number)
        room.type = request.json.get('type', room.type)
        room.email_signature = request.json.get('email_signature', room.email_signature)
        room.email_signature_en = request.json.get('email_signature_en', room.email_signature_en)
        images = request.json.get('images')
        if images == '':
            if room.images:
                relative_image_path = room.images.replace("/public/imgs/room_image/", "")
                full_image_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FACILITY_IMAGE_FOLDER'], relative_image_path)
                print('Deleting image:', full_image_path)
                if os.path.exists(full_image_path):
                    os.remove(full_image_path)
            room.images = ''
        else:
            room.images = images
        db.session.commit()
        return room_schema.jsonify(room)
    return jsonify({"error": "Room not found"}), 404
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

def save_room_image_file(file):
    random_string = uuid.uuid4().hex
    filename = file.filename
    extension = filename.rsplit('.', 1)[-1] if '.' in filename else ''
    final_filename = f"{random_string}.{extension}" if extension else random_string
    
    path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FACILITY_IMAGE_FOLDER'], final_filename)
    os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(path), exist_ok=True)
    file.save(path)
    
    return f"/public/imgs/room_image/{final_filename}"

@app.route("/upload-room-image", methods=["POST"])
def upload_room_image():
    if 'file' not in request.files:
        return jsonify({"error": "No file part"}), 400

    file = request.files['file']
    if file.filename == '':
        return jsonify({"error": "No selected file"}), 400

    if not allowed_file(file.filename):
        return jsonify({"error": "File type not allowed"}), 400
    
    old_file_path = request.form.get('old_file_path')
    if old_file_path:
        relative_image_path = old_file_path.replace("/public/imgs/room_image/", "")
        full_image_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FACILITY_IMAGE_FOLDER'], relative_image_path)
        if os.path.exists(full_image_path):
            os.remove(full_image_path)
    room_image_path = save_room_image_file(file)
    return jsonify({"filePath": room_image_path}), 200


@app.route("/delete-uploaded-room-image", methods=["DELETE"])
def delete_uploaded_room_file():
    image_path = request.json.get('image_path')
    if not image_path:
        print('No image path provided')
        return jsonify({"error": "No image path provided"}), 400

    relative_image_path = image_path.replace("/public/imgs/room_image/", "")
    full_image_path = os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FACILITY_IMAGE_FOLDER'], relative_image_path)
    print('Full image path to delete:', full_image_path)
    
    if os.path.exists(full_image_path):
        try:
            os.remove(full_image_path)
            print('Image deleted successfully:', full_image_path)
            return jsonify({"message": "Image deleted successfully"}), 200
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error deleting image:', e)
            return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500
    else:
        print('Image not found:', full_image_path)
        return jsonify({"error": "Image not found"}), 404


Here are the logs that are output when trying to delete an image:
When the delete icon is clicked in the UI, the following logs in F12 of website are shown:


File changed, isImageRemoved set to false
File removed, isImageRemoved set to true
Marked for deletion in roomIndex: true
Marked for deletion in UploadRoomImage: true
File removed, oldFilePath: /public/imgs/room_image/bf8c0bda160a4db099ebcd6c9297216f.PNG
File changed, isImageRemoved set to false

When I click "OK" to submit the edit:
OK button clicked, submitting edit
isImageRemoved = false

Despite the  being set to true and then false, the image file remains on the server and the path in the database is not updated.isImageRemoved.
In logs of Flask:
-  print('Deleting image:', full_image_path) of router /edit-room .
- print('No image path provided') , print('Full image path to delete:', full_image_path), print('Image deleted successfully:', full_image_path) and even print('Error deleting image:', e) as well as `print('Image not found: ', full_image_path)` of router /delete-uploaded-room-image are not displayed on the Flask terminal screen.
That really confused me.

Issues:


The image does not get deleted from the directory.
The image path in the database remains unchanged.

I suspect there might be an issue with how the state or the asynchronous operations are handled.

just some hints as i'm not knowledgeable about react/flask: something is wrong with your onSubmitEditRoom that's where you're calling flask and flask is never called. logs from that function are missing too

Thanks for suggestion. Honestly, I also think I made a mistake in "onSubmitEditRoom" but I really don't know where it went wrong because I checked the logs of both the backend and the frontend. Programming is really difficult  :'(
